# How can I get the date and version of drivers in C#?

Tags: c#

This is my code, I can get name, description...

```
ManagementClass MgmtClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_SystemDriver");

foreach (ManagementObject mo in MgmtClass.GetInstances())
{
  name=mo["Name"];
  Dis=mo["Description"];
  ...
}
```

How can I get the date and version of drivers?

Comment: If an answer gives you the info you were looking for then you should mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should start from researching [Win32_PnPSignedDriver Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394354(v=VS.85).aspx) and [Win32_PnPEntity Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353(v=VS.85).aspx)

**EXAMPLE**

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPSignedDriver");
                    ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();

                    foreach (var manObj in moc)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Device Name: {0}\r\nDeviceID: {1}\r\nDriverDate: {2}\r\nDriverVersion: {3}\r\n==============================\r\n", manObj["FriendlyName"], manObj["DeviceID"], manObj["DriverDate"], manObj["DriverVersion"]);
                    }
```

Comment: the problem that my drivers is not PnP, do I have another idea?

Comment: Not every driver is PnP!