# Hardware supported OS functions

Tags: operating-system, hardware-interface, systems-programming

I would like to know major hardware supported operating system(generic) functions or the categories of that. Is there any link or reference materials I can refer?

Answer (score 1):

I would try [Wikipedia's comparison of operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_operating_systems).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) .NET library.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can loop through ManagementObjects to get information on the drivers currently installed...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394354%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Also see this post:
[How can I get the date and version of drivers in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335003/how-can-i-get-the-date-and-version-of-drivers-in-c)